# Copy/Paste VBA Script Recorder Logs Wrong

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, rows

A few issues: Script is linked to a form ctrl button that runs `Update Data` every minute. This runs `Copy Data` and copies row `A39:T39` and pastes that row in the other sheet. That is the intent. But it doesn't paste right. Need to past in a row not a column starting w/ a time stamp on the other sheet in `A2`. `Stop Recording Data` is linked to a form ctrl button to cancel `Update Data` but that doesn't work either.

```
    Sub UpdateData()
     Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "UpdateData"
     CopyData
    End Sub
    
    Sub CopyData()
     Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet, cpyRng As Range, logRng As Long
    
     Application.StatusBar = "Recording Dashboard Started"
     Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard")
     Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Log")
     Set cpyRng = sht1.Range("A39:T39")
     logRng = sht2.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
     sht2.Range("A2") = Now
     cpyRng.Copy sht2.Cells(2, logRng)
    End Sub
    
    Sub StopRecordingData()
     Application.StatusBar = "Recording Dashboard Stopped"
     Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "UpdateData", False
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code into an own module.
To start logging, call **StartRecordingData()**
and for stopping call **StopRecordingData()**

```
Option Explicit

Dim boolLoggingActive As Boolean
    
    Public Sub StartRecordingData()
     Application.StatusBar = "Recording Dashboard Started"
     boolLoggingActive = True
     UpdateData
    End Sub
    Public Sub StopRecordingData()
     Application.StatusBar = "Recording Dashboard Stopped"
     boolLoggingActive = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub UpdateData()
        If boolLoggingActive = True Then
            Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "UpdateData"
            CopyData
        End If
    End Sub
    
    Private Sub CopyData()
     Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet, cpyRng As Range, logRng As Long
    
     Application.StatusBar = "Recording Dashboard Started"
     Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard")
     Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Log")
     Set cpyRng = sht1.Range("A39:T39")
     
     Dim rngLogTargetBeginningCell As Range
     Set rngLogTargetBeginningCell = sht2.Rows(sht2.Rows.Count).Columns(1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
     
     rngLogTargetBeginningCell = Now
     Dim rngLastCellSelection As Range
     
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' Stop Updating Graphic during data copy
     Set rngLastCellSelection = Selection ' remember the last selection because pasting will change the active cell
     cpyRng.Copy
     rngLogTargetBeginningCell.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
     Application.CutCopyMode = False ' Remove the copy area marker
     rngLastCellSelection.Select    ' reselect the old cell
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True  ' update graphics again
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. This works a lot better. The start, stop, and timestamp work great. But I noticed the copy/paste part is actually pasting the formulas in `A39:T39` and not pasting just the values from those formulas. Any idea why?

Comment: I changed the makro. Now only values should get copied. Also you don't see the copy marker around the source cells. If you are already using Application.Screenupdating by another makro, you have to keep in mind to sync the settings so they don't interfere each other.

Comment: this works great thank you for the help. I ran it over night with no issues so far.