# Copy/Paste Data Log Based on a Condition

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, copy-paste, worksheet-function

The following code copies a row of data from a Dashboard to a Data_Log as you repeatedly click the Start button. I am trying to add a condition that each time a `Yes` appears in column `D` of the Time Log copy the data from the Dashboard to the Data_Log and only click the Start button once to initiate as it should run continuously until you hit the Stop button.

The problem is I cannot copy the data when the `Yes` condition appears on the Time_Log.

Logic -> Condition of `Yes` appears on the Time_Log -> copy from Dashboard -> paste to Data_Log -> continues to copy/paste as the `Yes` increments on the Time_Log with time moving forward. Thank you for your help.

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Dim LoggingActive As Boolean
Public Sub StartLoggingData()
    Application.StatusBar = "Logging Dashboard Started"
    LoggingActive = True
    CopyData
End Sub
Public Sub StopLoggingData()
    Application.StatusBar = "Logging Dashboard Stopped"
    LoggingActive = False
End Sub
 
Private Sub CopyData()
 
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet, sht3 As Worksheet, cpyRng As Range, logRng As Long, rngLogTargetBeginningCell As Range, rngLastCellSelection As Range, r As Long, lastRow As Range
 
    If LoggingActive = True Then

        Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard")
        Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data_Log")
        Set sht3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Time_Log")
        Set cpyRng = sht1.Range("A39:Q39")
        Set rngLogTargetBeginningCell = sht2.Rows(sht2.Rows.Count).Columns(1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        Set rngLastCellSelection = Selection ' remember the last selection because pasting will change the active cell
 
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' Stop Updating Graphic during data copy
        lastRow = sht3.Cells(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For r = 4 To lastRow
            If sht3.Range("D" & r).Value = "Yes" Then
                cpyRng.Copy
                rngLogTargetBeginningCell.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                rngLastCellSelection.Select    ' reselect the old cell
            End If
        Next r
    End If
    Application.CutCopyMode = False ' Remove the copy area marker
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True  ' update graphics again
End Sub
```

Comment: Was this continous loop not included in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71373500/17172829) of our last question? Or did i misunderstand your question. Or how ist the Yes status set?

Comment: In our last question if you are referring to the `UpdateData` sub based on the `Application.OnTime` event to keep the continuous loop active I removed that sub as I cannot use the `Application.OnTime`. The `Yes` status is not using VBA. It simply looks at the `Now()` function inside of cell `C2` on the Time_Log sheet and uses `If` the incremented Static Time is <= `Now()` report `Yes` in all of column `D`.  It is a work around of `Application.OnTime` because `Applcation.Ontime` only works if the workbook is in ready mode.

Comment: Have you tried to use the `SheetChange` event to trigger our loop?

Comment: I have not yet. Was just working really hard to find a workaround for the `Application.OnTime` as this was causing so many problems. I do have a `Worksheet Calculate` event in one other worksheet. I hope the `SheetChange` and `SheetCalculate` don't interfere with each other like the `Application.OnTime` did.

Comment: Have you tried to avoid different events. So only using one event (e.g. update data) calls also the additional calculation and your data log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lastRow` is typed  as a `Range` instead of a Numeric data type.
`wsTime_Log.Cells(Rows.Count)` refers to column 1 which is empty.

> ```
> lastRow As Range
> lastRow = wsTime_Log.Cells(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
> ```

`rngLogTargetBeginningCell` should be determined inside the loop.

### Corrections

> ```
> lastRow As Long
> lastRow = wsTime_Log.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
> ```

### Refactored Code

```
Dim LoggingActive As Boolean

Public Sub StartLoggingData()
    Application.StatusBar = "Logging Dashboard Started"
    LoggingActive = True
    CopyData
End Sub

Public Sub StopLoggingData()
    Application.StatusBar = "Logging Dashboard Stopped"
    LoggingActive = False
End Sub
 
Private Sub CopyData()
    LoggingActive = True
    
    Dim r As Long, lastRow As Long
    Dim ValidationRange As Range
    Set ValidationRange = TimeLogValidationRange
    
    If LoggingActive = True Then

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' Stop Updating Graphic during data copy
    
        For r = 1 To ValidationRange.Rows.Count
            If ValidationRange.Cells(r, 1).Value = "Yes" Then
                With DashboardDataRange
                    NewData_LogRow.Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
                End With
            End If
        Next r
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True  ' update graphics again
End Sub

Function TimeLogValidationRange() As Range
    With wsTime_Log
        Set TimeLogValidationRange = .Range("A1", .UsedRange).Columns("D")
        With TimeLogValidationRange
            Set TimeLogValidationRange = TimeLogValidationRange.Offset(3).Resize(.Rows.Count - 3)
        End With
    End With
End Function

Function DashboardDataRange() As Range
    Set DashboardDataRange = wsDashboard.Range("A39:Q39")
End Function

Function NewData_LogRow() As Range
    With wsData_Log
        Set NewData_LogRow = .UsedRange.Columns(1)
        Set NewData_LogRow = NewData_LogRow.Offset(NewData_LogRow.Rows.Count).Resize(1).EntireRow
    End With
End Function

Function wsDashboard() As Worksheet
    Set wsDashboard = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard")
End Function

Function wsData_Log() As Worksheet
    Set wsData_Log = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data_Log")
End Function

Function wsTime_Log() As Worksheet
    Set wsTime_Log = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Time_Log")
End Function
```

I like to create helper functions for all my ranges.  This allows me to test exactly what is being referenced like this:

```
Application.Goto TimeLogValidationRange
Application.Goto DashboardDataRange
Application.Goto NewData_LogRow
```

Comment: @TinManwe are close here. The `Application.Goto` is clever haven't used that yet. Just did and it helped. As I was debugging your answer I noticed is was pasting `NewData_LogRow` range way down on Row 6,848 of the `Data_Log` how can I get that up on row 2? Also, it appears to not be looping as the only way it copies the next `Yes` that appears is if a `Stop` and `Start` the sub over again.

Comment: Based on your image I  moved the range down to row 4 `Set TimeLogValidationRange = TimeLogValidationRange.Offset(3)` and then `.Resize(.Rows.Count - 3)`  and then dropped the last 3 empty rows.

Comment: Yes, that is correct for that part of the code. I was refering to the `Set NewData_LogRow ` it appears to be placing `A39:Q39` in my `Data Log` sheet way down on row 6,848. Would like it at row 2. Also, it appears to not be looping as the only way it copies the next `Yes` that appears is if a `Stop` and `Start` the sub over again. Thank you for helping me with this. It means a lot.

Comment: @mjac Do you want to insert a new row at row 2?

Comment: @mjac Your original code did not loop either,  How often is to supposed to loop?

Comment: It is suppose to loop each time a new `Yes` appears in column `D`. So column `D` is tied to the current time (not using VBA). As time moves forward more `Yes` pop up in column `D` and this code is suppose to watch  column `D`. As each minute passes by...a new `Yes` appears for that minute and then it copies a fresh new `A39:Q39`.

Comment: @mjac Loops and `Application.OnTime` are problematic.  You should try the `Worksheet_Change` event first.  Watch: [Excel VBA: The Magic of the Worksheet Change Event}(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TYyPrqqFgVg&t=6s)

Comment: Your right `Application.OnTime` is plagued w/ bugs. That's why I got rid of it and made this workaround. I also have a `Worksheet_Calculate` event in my other sheet. Hopefully the `Change` event and the `Calculate` event work ok together with no interference.